# const doesn't seem to pass value through functions

Tags: javascript

I define two DOM selectors as constants but I can't seem to call them through functions. Essentially I should be able to pass two constants as arguments of a function where one gets it's display style set to block and the other set to none.

My JS is:

```
const divOne = document.querySelector("#divOne");
const divTwo = document.querySelector("#divTwo");

function showHide(show, hide){
    show.style.display = "block";
    hide.style.display = "none";
}

function changeDisplay(arg) {
    //do some other bits
    showHide(divOne, divTwo);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to change and I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
        at showHide
```

Am I not able to pass querySelectors through functions?

Comment: How are you calling “changeDisplay”? Where is it being called?

Comment: Could you pls post your full code including the HTML?

Comment: required html how you doing it like said by @urvashi. but i added answer if you add proper html it will not give error. check answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the dom has both "#divOne" and "#divTwo". If they are not available then the const variable will hold undefined

Comment: Thanks, I looked and looked and looked but couldn't see any difference. I retyped it and it seemed to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass anything with functions in js )
It's difficult to say what is happening here just looking at pieces of puzzle but my suggestion is to check when do you actually call changeDisplay or showHide. I mean is your DOM built and ready?
Maybe at the time of calling those functions your DOM tree is not ready